# Alternate spell count system for wizard

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

I am playing a wizard, and realized that my DM is unlikely to know that they should provide spells for my wizard to copy (also it doesn't fit the character concept). Has there been any word on a level up system for wizard that has spell counts by level?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind looking up alternate rules, if you're saying that your DM doesn't "know that they should provide spells for my wizard to copy"? Sounds like a Session 0 is in order so everyone is on the same page...

Comment: Hi Peregrine! Can you explain what you mean by spell counts increasing as part of a level up system? Are you referring to an alternative set of rules like those found in Xanathar's/Tasha's which would automatically grant access to certain spells? Or are you referring to any 3rd party rules set that does something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wizards already have one in the PHB.

PHB pg. 114: "Spellbook" and "Learning Spells of 1st Level and Higher", emphasis mine:

> At 1st level, you have a spellbook containing **six 1st-level wizard spells** of your choice.

> Each time you gain a wizard level, **you can add two wizard spells of your choice to your spellbook for free**. Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots, as shown on the Wizard table. On your adventures, you **might find other spells that you can add to your spellbook** (see the "Your Spellbook" sidebar).

That leaves us with 6 at 1st level, and 2 more per level beyond 1st. Any copiable spells your DM provides are in addition to this base amount.